# box2d-js element with external image

Tags: javascript, html, physics, box2d

So far in the samples of varies box2d js implementation I can find only element defined in shapes (ball/box/etc), is there a way to create an element defined by an image, e.g. a boulder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `b2PolyDef` and `b2PolyShape` objects to create polygons.

[This documentation](http://www.kyucon.com/doc/box2d/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolyDef.html) is meant for AS3 but it is relatively simple to figure out the JavaScript equivalent.

If you wanted to automate the mapping from an image's bounding box to the polygon, you could use canvas and `getImageData()` to seek through the pixels looking for non transparent (assuming your image has a transparent background). This is probably more effort than it is worth though.

Also see [Understanding custom polygons in Box2D](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/19/understanding-custom-polygons-in-box2d/).

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's helpful for me to understand how to create a poly shape. However I still don't see how to draw an image (http://www.webindia123.com/astrology/Images/diamond.jpg) for a poly shape element. If I use cocos2d (http://cocos2d-javascript.org/), I can easily draw an element with image by using cocos.nodes.Sprite.create. Just want to know how to do that in plain box2djs.

Comment: @green: I'm not familiar with that other library but I will have a dig and let you know  :)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve a same kind of problem when i came across this brilliant [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27407/box2dweb-and-images). Hope this will help you.