# Box2dWeb and Images

Tags: javascript, box2d

How do I import and attach a PNG or GIF to a shape in Box2dWeb?

The best resource I could find online is at: http://www.jeremyhubble.com/box2d.html

However, this "tutorial" doesn't give much explanation about how images are actually used. So it is clearly possible, but I can't get the userData trick to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567823/box2d-js-element-with-external-image

Comment: Hey @Derek that article doesn't quite answer my question. In fact, he seems to be having the same problem and no one was able to answer it.

How does one attach an image, NOT make a polygon. :D

Comment: Maybe it is impossible at this time? Anyway, I know Angry Birds is using Box2D in their HTML5 version and I know it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this for you over on [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27407/box2dweb-and-images/27930#27930) now (along with an example), but here's the bottom line:

You are generally responsible for rendering the state of your box2d world - the "userData trick" you refer to is not really to do with the box2d framework.

userData is a placeholder for arbitrary data that you want to associate to a body. This could be anything - a string, function, object, etc. This data is typically used to help you render your world during the update loop, which is exactly what the resource you linked to does - If you look at the processObjects function it uses the imgsrc value to create an Image object and draws it onto the canvas at the correct location. (This isn't really a good idea because the image is created once per object per iteration - I would suggest it should only be created once)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: You may try this new link: http://codingowl.com/readblog.php?blogid=134

Maybe this site can help -- [box2dweb.com/blog/2012/05/01/attaching-image-贴图/](http://box2dweb.com/blog/2012/05/01/attaching-image-%E8%B4%B4%E5%9B%BE/)